# проблема с Button (background)

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, button, background

Хочу сделать кастомное диалоговое окно. Но возникает проблема с стилизацией кнопки.
когда ввожу `android:background="@drawble/button_yes"` то меняется только форма но не цвет и не понимаю что не так.
customize_dialog_gps.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_yes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_yes" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

button_yes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#4CAF50"/>
    <corners android:radius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422562/how-to-change-theme-for-alertdialog

Answer (score 0):

Решением моем проблемы стало использования `AppCompatButton` вместо `Button`